# VS2008/VS2010 and TFS 2018: The user name [ID] is not a fully-qualified user name. Pareter name: workspaceOwner

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

While trying to open source control explorer in VS 2008 (when you are connected to TFS 2017 or above) you get the following error:

*`The user name [ID] is not a fully-qualified user name. Pareter name: workspaceOwner`*

How do we fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I found the solution. Here is the link:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/16924/vs2008-and-tfs-2017-the-user-name-id-is-not-a-full.html

and here is the summary, please download and install the following GDR's for VS 2008 and VS2010 respectively:

[VS2008 GDR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2673642/a-gdr-update-for-visual-studio-2008-sp1-is-available-to-add-support-for-team-foundation-server-2012-and-team-foundation-service-preview)

[VS2010 GDR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2736182/a-gdr-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1-is-available-to-add-compatibility-support-for-visual-studio-2012-and-windows-8)